# Why does beforeEach() cancel the navigation triggered inside the component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a global route guard which uses `beforeEach` hook:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const isAuthenticated = true; // or false check if the user is logged in

    if (to.matched[0].name === 'Dashboard' && !isAuthenticated) {
        next({ name: 'Login' });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

But when i try to call `$router.push` or `$router.replace` methods from the route components like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.$auth.login(this.loginData).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Dashboard' });
    });
},
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/login" to "/dashboard" with a new navigation.
    at createRouterError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008)
    at createNavigationCancelledError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1990)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2337)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1944)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951)
    at runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1955)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2335)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1944)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1948)
```

Now the question is why does this happen? And is there any solution for it?

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove everything from `beforeEach` except one line `next()`?  If not, the problem is somewhere else.  Maybe you can show the template where you're calling `onSubmit`

Comment: if `isAuthenticated` is false on line 4 in the `beforeEach` hook - it will cancel the navigation. So you have to add `.catch()` to your `$router.push()` statement

Comment: @Dan You were right. The problem was from the form which called the `onSubmit` method. It didn't have a `preventDefault` so caused another redirection which was cancelling the Vue Router navigation.